# Export excel form Power BI using Power Automate

Tags: excel, powerbi, power-automate, azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to extract data from a specific table in power bi and export it to an excel file for further analysis recursively (1 a week).
I came across a solution, but I am encountering some issues. Here is the solution I found: [image: Solution 1]

1. The solution I found only works on an import mode dataset, but my final goal is to run the query against a dataset in live connection with an Azure Analysis Services database. Unfortunately, my current solution cannot support live connection datasets, and I cannot change the connection mode of the dataset.
2. I attempted to use Power BI Report Builder, but I am unable to connect my report to Azure due to internal policies.
3. I cannot use PowerShell or other similar solutions because it needs to be easy to maintain.
4. I cannot export data in xlsx format with live connection [image: export xlsx]

Despite these constraints, I am hoping for suggestions for a workaround :)

Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dataflow that reads data from the db and a dataset that reads data from the dataflow.
The power automate flow runs smoothly